# Registering the app to cast developer console using Styled Media Reciever

Tags: android, chromecast, castcompanionlibrary

I have registered my app with **Styled Media Receiver** and received my app Id. Also for this, in the app I am using Cast Companion Library. I have already done the testing using the same id of Cast-Videos tutorial of github and works fine. But when i use my ID received after the registration process, the cast device is connected but does not play the video. What might be the reason for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since it is your own app id, you should be able to connect chrome debugger to your chromecast and look at the console log (make sure you turn on logs) and provide more information on the log on the receiver, as well as the sender.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://202.166.193.114:8081/wlinkvodorigin/mobile/eng/Taken3.mp4/playlist.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.gstatic.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
media_player.js:21

[224.959s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK

this is what i get while debugging from browser

Comment: For this check your url first.. i think the problem is with your Url..It might have been restricted due to some reason

Comment: thanks that worked out :) the problem was with video url which was down.